# Use of a year with "launched"

Tags: prepositions, sentence-construction

What's the most correct way to indicate the year in which a testing campaign has been started?

> 2020 [company] launched a campaign to investigate [...]

> In 2020, [company] launched a campaign to investigate [...]

> [Company] launched 2020 a campaign to investigate [...]

> [Company] launched a campaign to investigate [...] in 2020.

The first one sounds the more natural to me, but I'm not sure. Are there even better ways to write this sentence?

Comment: Either the second or the fourth, depending on whether you want to emphasise the year or the action. It's not idiomatic to leave out the _in_ before a year number.

Comment: I would prefer the second, which clearly states that the campaign was launched in 2020. The fourth can be interpreted in two ways, only one of which is what you want The other interpretation is that the investigation was to take place during 2020, in which case the campaign may have been launched earlier.

Comment: Years typically take "in" unless used adjectivally: "The 2020 investigation etc" Or, as a stand-alone noun: "Two thousand and twenty **was the year** that etc."